# Sync another Model

Tags: laravel-5.5, eloquent

I have a view for a `location`. This `location`, that has different `services`. They are both linked as has many in the model (n-m relation) in the model `LocationService`.

In this view, it is possible to select different `tags` for each `service` of the `location`. I have a model called `location_service_tag`, that has the id of the `location_service` and the id of the `tags`.

Now I want to store the `tags` of the `location_service` combination using the **sync** method. How is it possible to store this information?

Here is an example (The IDs are free chosen):

I have the view with the `location` 1.
This location has 2 `services` with the id 11, 22.
They are stored in `location_service` with the ids 111,122.
The location_service 111 has the tag id 1111, 2222, the location_service 122 has the tags 2222,4444.

Now I want to store these tags into location_service_tag using sync. How is this possible?

I thought it might be possible somehow like this, but it is not.

```
  foreach($request->servicetags as $servicetag){
    if(count($servicetag)>0){
      //Final statement must be true, because we want to override e.g. if one is deleted or inserted
      $location->locationservice()->tags()->sync($servicetag, true);
    }else{
      //There are no services, submit an empty array
      $location->locationservice()->tags()->sync([], true);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it with:

```
  //Save relational Data of services
  //If there are services, add the, else add empty array
  if(isset($request->locationservices)){
    foreach($request->locationservices as $key => $locationservice){
      if(count($locationservice)>0){
        LocationService::find($key)->tags()->sync($locationservice, true);
      }else{
        LocationService::find($key)->tags()->sync([], true);
      }
    }
  }
```

The key has the locationservice_id as key and the value of the loop has the selected tag_ids as an array for each locationservice.